# Return specific matched (sub) value with grep in linux

Tags: ping, parsing, string-manipulation

I'm running a Zabbix agent (logging software) on Ubuntu and wish to ping an internal IPIP/GRE Tunnel to constantly measure the quality of the connection.

Now a Zabbix agent does not by default allow a ping command to be done to an internal tunnel, but luckily they do allow to create "userparameters", basically it lets you execute a single unix shell command and feed the data to your software.

To do so I need to run an fping/ping command that retrieves a single value for zabbix. I want this value to be the number of decimal seconds or miliseconds of latency or 0 on no connection for anything over 1 second. Below I've already worked out a command that does 5 pings to the tunnel IP then returns the averages.

(the IP-address below is example data)
this is what I've gotten so far:

```
fping -e -q -p 1000 -c 5 8.8.4.4 2> /dev/null | grep -oP '[0-9\.]+/([0-9\.]+)/[0-9\.]+$'
```

The full return string looks like this:

```
8.8.4.4 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 5/5/0%, min/avg/max = 2.78/2.94/3.19"
```

Now the grep result is this:

```
2.78/2.94/3.19
```

I want to consistently obtain the second value (2.94 above), my question then is, what is the most effective way to do so in a single command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `sed` instead of `grep`, so your filter becomes:

```
... | sed -n 's%^.* = .* = .*/\(.*\)/.*%\1%pg'
```

Notes:-

- Because we are matching the `/` character, I have replaced the normal string delimiter by `%` to simplify the expression by avoiding the need to escape `/`.
- We are matching the whole line and replacing it by what comes between two slashes after two equals signs, delimited by `\(` and `\)` in the match string and `\1` in the replacement.
- We don't output anything (`-n`) except on lines where there are matches (`%pg`).

To simplify my illustration I've used `.*` for the numbers. You can use `[0-9\.]+`, but you'll need to use extended RE with `grep -rn ...`

If you haven't used `sed` before, I recommend [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, if I run the following command, I get an empty result:
fping -e -q -p 1000 -c 5 8.8.4.4 | sed -n 's%^.* = .* = .*/\(.*\)/.*%\1%pg'

However if I run the command manually then copy the result in an echo, it does work, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: apparently fping always outputs to stderr instead of stdin, I resolved this by including 2>&1 at the end of the fping command

Comment: In `bash` you can shorten the redirection to `fping ... |& sed ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `cut -d/ -f8` ? As in:

```
echo '8.8.4.4 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 5/5/0%, min/avg/max = 2.78/2.94/3.19"' | cut -d/ -f8
```

Comment: This also worked, the sed solution seems more flexible though :) 
Thanks anyway!

Comment: This is a good solution, unless there are extra lines in different formats in the output from `fping`: each extra line in the input to `cut` will give a blank line in the output. To eliminate these you need an extra filter `... | grep -v '^$'`.

Comment: Of course `sed` or `awk` would have worked - I attempted to provide the simplest answer to the stated problem :)